# Using Google Truth with Android text views

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, google-truth

This may be obvious, but I can't seem to find a better way to handle this. I'm switching my project from using AssertJ to using Truth for several reasons that are beyond the scope of this question. In AssertJ, I could work easily with Android "string-like" classes. For instance, this was valid in AssertJ:

```
assertThat(mEmailEditText.getText()).isEmpty();
```

But in Truth, it looks like the core Truth library doesn't recognize how to convert from Editable/CharSequence into String. That means I have to write a lot of the following:

```
assertThat((String) mEmailEditText.getText()).isEmpty();
```

...which kind of defeats the purpose of using Truth. I suspect I could write my own custom subject for CharSequence, but I was curious if there was a more accepted practice for this.

Comment: Casting with `(String)` is risky, since [`.getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) doesn't actually promise it returns a `String`. I'd agree with Diego's suggestion to simply call `.toString()`, but you can also file a [feature request](https://github.com/google/truth/issues) if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
assertThat(mEmailEditText.getText().toString()).isEmpty();
```